# How to use Apache Beam FileIO writeDynamic to output audio files from byte arrays?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are using Apache Beam to process streamed data from pubsub source to GCS sink with dynamic filenames. We are able to write text files, but not wav files.

We are able to write out our byte array string (linear16 wav encoding) working with StringUtf8Coder but have a compilation error with ByteArrayEncoder

// THIS WORKS:

```java
pipelineBeginStage
  .apply(
    FileIO.<String, KamiAppData>writeDynamic()
          .by((SerializableFunction<KamiAppData, String>) input -> input.GCSurl)
          .via(
             Contextful.fn((SerializableFunction<KamiAppData, String>) input -> input.audioStream),
             TextIO.sink())
          .to(outputBucket)
          .withNaming(url -> FileNaming.getNaming(url, "wav"))
          .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
          .withNumShards(1));
```

// THIS YIELDS A COMPILATION ERROR:

```java
pipelineBeginStage
  .apply(
    FileIO.<String, KamiAppData>writeDynamic()
          .by((SerializableFunction<KamiAppData, String>) input -> input.GCSurl)
          .via(
            Contextful.fn((SerializableFunction<KamiAppData, byte[]>) input -> input.audioStream.getBytes()),
            TextIO.sink())
          .to(outputBucket)
          .withNaming(url -> FileNaming.getNaming(url, "wav"))
          .withDestinationCoder(ByteArrayCoder.of())
          .withNumShards(1));
```

The error we get is:

```
cannot resolve method 'via(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful.Fn<InputT,OutputT>>,org.apache.beam.sdk.TextIO.Sink)'
```

How do we make this compile and write the audio to file using Apache Beam APIs?

Comment: `TextIO.sink()` is a `Sink<String>` (which makes sense since it is called "text" IO). And the signature of `FileIO.via()` expects that the output of the `contextfulFn` is going to be of the same as the type argument of the sink (which makes sense since you want to write elements of the same type you are producing by the `contextfulFn`). So the first example works because the output of the `contextfulFn` is a string and the sink also takes strings. In the second example you want to output bytes but the sink takes strings, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Anton's explanation in the comment above looks very clear to me.

Just want to add that for it to work with byte type, you may need to implement your own `FileIO.Sink<byte[]>` class.