# Java: How to windowed compressed byte-writes to Google cloud storage with dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to do a dataflow job that collectes incomming bute arrays and writes them windowed and compressed to GCS.
Basically the same as https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-to-gcs
But instead of Strings in the class WriteOneFilePerWindow I want to write byte[].

Just swapping the types introduces problems. Because the used TextIO.write()... is sutable only for Strings.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, [TextIO.write](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html#write--) is really targeted at writing strings.  You probably want to use [FileIO.write](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html#write--) and use a custom sink that allows you to write a byte array.

Another relevant question: [How to use Apache Beam FileIO writeDynamic to output audio files from byte arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725569/how-to-use-apache-beam-fileio-writedynamic-to-output-audio-files-from-byte-array)